# How do I convert a value received from an enum to String in Swift?

Tags: swift, enums

I've created the below code in Swift.  When I run it, I get something like:

Today is (Enum Value)
  Monday and Wednesday's class is CIS 110

What I want to get is the name of the day (for example, "Monday").  When I run the code in debug mode and watch the variable, "weekday", I see the day of the week.  However, when the code finishes running, I end up with "(Enum Value)".

CODE:

```
import Foundation
import Darwin


//weekdays
enum Weekdays: Int{
    case Monday = 1, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
}

//get random day of the week
func getDay() ->Int{
    let day = Int(1 + arc4random_uniform(7)) //random number 1 - 7
    return day
}


//determine schedule
var schedule: String = ""

func getSchedule(day: Int) -> String {
    switch day{
    case 1, 3:
        schedule = "Monday and Wednesday's class is CIS 110"
    case 2, 4:
        schedule = "Tuesday and Thursday's classes are ENG 111 and PSY 150"
    default:
        schedule = "It's the weekend! Have fun!"
    }
    return schedule
}
let day = getDay()
//take that random day and use the number the rawValue of the 
//Weekdays to get the weekday
let weekday = Weekdays(rawValue: day)!

println("Today is \(weekday)")
println(getSchedule(day))
```

Comment: You can't use the enum's values directly. So you need to define a dictionary mapping the enum to strings.

Comment: If you change Int to String, the `rawValue` will be `"Monday"` and so on (in Swift 2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Adopt Printable (called CustomStringConvertible in Swift 2.0) and implement a `description` override that does what you want.